# Creating a user editable area of a site - adding to a users collection

Tags: php, database, content-management-system

I'm trying to create a section of a website where users can login and add products to a collections area where they have saved collections of products.

A simple example would be:

Logged in user - Finds product - clicks add to collection - collection is saved for when they log back on.

Also there may be more than one collection eg "add to: Collection 1, Collection 2 etc"

If anyone can help or just point me in the right direction it would be great.

Additional info: I'm a good front end developer with some php knowledge.

Comment: Use php sessions for login. And you will need many mysql queries for the functioning of logged in users interaction with collection.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create a section of a website where users can login and
>   add products to a collections area where they have saved collections
>   of products.

Well, for now I can see four tables: users, products, collections, collections_products (association).

> A simple example would be: Logged in user - Finds product - clicks add
>   to collection - collection is saved for when they log back on.

Login - verify if the user and password exists in the table and store the user data in the session.

Page 1: provide a form with fields that the user can filter to return products

Page 2: show the filters and the products with a link to add to collections.

When the user clicks in the link to add to collections, you can provide a modal dialog with a list of collections and every collection with one checkbox. The list can have the checkbox of a collection already selected if the association already exists.

Example:

Product: My Procuct

```
Add to collections
[ x ] collection one (already associated)
[   ] collection two
[   ] collection ...
[   ] collection ...

[ Save Associations ]
```

**Note: in your checkboxes you have to use a name like `collection[]` so the php will handle as an array.**

To save the association of the product and the collections, you can delete all associations for the user product and insert just those that return checked.

Well I think that's a start.